# Understanding PHP's --with-sybase-ct option to get MS SQL working on *nix

Tags: php, sql-server, sap-ase

I'm configuring for the first time a PHP5.5 installation on a Redhat server.

I'm following a tutorial which help me to install MSSql driver, there is no built-in one, so I should use Sybase's.

The [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/sybase.installation.php) tells to compile PHP with the following option:

```
--with-sybase-ct[=DIR]
```

I don't understand why I should provide a directory path, I install PHP on a web server, not a database server, why does it require the sybase directory? Is it a lib folder I should provide? But in this case what sources should I download?